# the click event of the button in gridview not working

Tags: c#, gridview

I create a column in the gridview within this there is a button and in the event that buttonclik Button will add a simple code to test the button that worked, but not working. When I click the button and attempt to trace the code of the button event even comes to the breaking point. What can I do? Please help me

Thank you
[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSXK.jpg)
[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDcj3.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean you put a breakpoint in the button's Click event handler, and it is not reached when you click the button?

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise it'll be impossible to help you and your question will most likely be closed.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! In case it is winforms: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..!

Comment: Yes i do, when i put a breakpoint in the button's Click event handle, it not entre there. Sorry my english, i don't speak english

Comment: How did you create the event handler? Did you click on the Button in the Designer? Did you write the subscribing code? Or did you not subscribe to it? Event handlers don't run by themselves, you need to subscribe to them somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not write much because I do not speak English, and also I'm new in the site. I use Windforms

Comment: yes I did I click on the Button in the Designer

Comment: OK. So the Designer created the subscription for you. It should work.

Comment: User42 Look at the picture of Example 2 to see where I execute the event